# Summing subsets of many dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have ~1.2k files that when converted into dataframes look like this:

```
df1
   A     B     C     D
0  0.1   0.5   0.2   C
1  0.0   0.0   0.8   C
2  0.5   0.1   0.1   H
3  0.4   0.5   0.1   H
4  0.0   0.0   0.8   C
5  0.1   0.5   0.2   C
6  0.1   0.5   0.2   C
```

Now, I have to subset each dataframe with a window of fixed size along the rows, and add its contents to a second dataframe, with all its values originally initialized to 0.

```
df_sum
   A    B    C   
0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
1  0.0  0.0  0.0 
2  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

For example, let's set the window size to 3. The first subset therefore will be

```
window = df.loc[start:end, 'A':'C']
window
   A     B     C 
0  0.1   0.5   0.2 
1  0.0   0.0   0.8 
2  0.5   0.1   0.1  

window.index = correct_index
df_sum = df_sum.add(window, fill_value=0)
df_sum
   A     B     C 
0  0.1   0.5   0.2 
1  0.0   0.0   0.8 
2  0.5   0.1   0.1
```

After that, the window will be the subset of `df1` from rows 1-4, then rows 2-5, and finally rows 3-6. Once the first file has been scanned, the second file will begin, until all file have been processed. As you can see, this approach relies on `df.loc` for the subset and `df.add` for the addition. However, despite the ease of coding, it is very inefficient. On my machine it takes about 5 minutes to process the whole batch of 1.2k files of 200 lines each. I know that an implementation based on numpy arrays is orders of magnitude faster (about 10 seconds), but a bit more complicated in terms of subsetting and adding. Is there any way to increase the performance of this method while stile using dataframe? For example substituting the `loc` with a more performing slice method.

Example:

```
def generate_index_list(window_size):
    before_offset = -(window_size - 1)// 2
    after_offset = (window_size - 1)// 2
    index_list = list()
    for n in range(before_offset, after_offset + 1):
        index_list.append(str(n))
    return index_list

window_size = 3
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, sep= '\t')
    starting_index = (window_size - 1)//2
    before_offset = (window_size - 1)// 2
    after_offset = (window_size -1)//2
    for index in df1.iterrows():
        if index < starting_index or index + before_offset + 1 > len(profile.index):
            continue
        indexes = generate_index_list(window_size) 
        window = df1.loc[index - before_offset:index + after_offset, 'A':'C']
        window.index = indexes
        df_sum = df_sum.add(window, fill_value=0)
```

Expected output:

```
df_sum
   A    B    C   
0  1.0  1.1  2.0 
1  1.0  1.1  2.0 
2  1.1  1.6  1.4
```

Comment: And what is `generate_index_list()`? For SO posts, we need a [mcve]. Also, if code works and you need advice on refactoring for efficiency, consider posting on [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's just a simple function to set the correct indexes for the `add`. Thank you for you insights, I'm still new to posting questions on SO

Comment: Can you the expected output to your question?

Comment: Done, hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a list of subsetted data frames with`.loc` and `.head`. Then run `groupby` aggregation after individual elements are concatenated.

```
window_size = 3

def window_process(file):
    csv_df = pd.read_csv(file, sep= '\t')

    window_dfs = [(csv_df.loc[i:,['A', 'B', 'C']]   # ROW AND COLUMN SLICE
                         .head(window)              # SELECT FIRST WINDOW ROWS
                         .reset_index(drop=True)    # RESET INDEX TO 0, 1, 2, ...
                  ) for i in range(df.shape[0])]  
                     
    sum_df = (pd.concat(window_dfs)                 # COMBINE WINDOW DFS
                .groupby(level=0).sum())            # AGGREGATE BY INDEX 
        
    return sum_df

# BUILD LONG DF FROM ALL FILES
long_df = pd.concat([window_process(f) for file in os.listdir('.')])

# FINAL AGGREGATION
df_sum = long_df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

---

Using posted data sample, below are the outputs of each `window_df`s:

```
     A    B    C
0  0.1  0.5  0.2
1  0.0  0.0  0.8
2  0.5  0.1  0.1

     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.8
1  0.5  0.1  0.1
2  0.4  0.5  0.1

     A    B    C
0  0.5  0.1  0.1
1  0.4  0.5  0.1
2  0.0  0.0  0.8

     A    B    C
0  0.4  0.5  0.1
1  0.0  0.0  0.8
2  0.1  0.5  0.2

     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.8
1  0.1  0.5  0.2
2  0.1  0.5  0.2

     A    B    C
0  0.1  0.5  0.2
1  0.1  0.5  0.2

     A    B    C
0  0.1  0.5  0.2
```

With final `df_sum` to show accuracy of `DataFrame.add()`:

```
df_sum
     A    B    C
0  1.2  2.1  2.4
1  1.1  1.6  2.2
2  1.1  1.6  1.4
```

Comment: The proposed solution works a little bit better than mine, but is still quite slow.

Comment: I almost guessed performance marginally changes (though readability is improved). See updated approach. Possibly using `DataFrame.sum` within a loop leads to [quadractic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451) similar to `append` or `concat` in a `for` loop. Edit uses `concat` on list comprehensions and `groupby` aggregation.